# Idiomatic way to test for non-nullishness

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, null, idioms, nullish-coalescing

JavaScript now provides `??` and `?.` to do things like find the first non-nullish expression or dereference an object if not null.

[Added: "[nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)" means "`null` or `undefined`", like the nullish coalescing operator].

Is there a good idiomatic way to simply test for non-nullishness? For instance, if I want to only call an `onChange()` handler if my value is non-nullish. That is:

```
someVal && onChange(someVal)
```

Obviously this is incorrect, because it would fail for falsy but non-nullish values (notably `0` and `''`).

Comment: What's wrong with `someVal != null` ?

Comment: @FelixKling Nothing! It's the right answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way is an `if` statement with a comparison against `null`:

```
if (someVal != null) onChange(someVal)
```

```
if (someVal != null) {
    onChange(someVal)
}
```

There is no operator for this. Some people [have expressed as desire](https://es.discourse.group/t/syntax-inverse-null-coalescing-operator/547) for an [extension to the *pipeline operator* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/issues/159) that would let you write you something like `someVal ?> onChange;`, but I don't know of any implementation of that idea.

Comment: Ah thank you, that's what I was looking for - the coerced comparison.